# Typescript: switch on object type not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, switch-statement

I encountered a strange problem while developing an angular app.
I wrote this piece of code some time ago and it's working perfectly:

```
selectedGeoArea: any

receiveStoreEvent(event) {
    switch (event.constructor) {
      case City:
        console.log("city")
        break
      case Province:
        console.log("province")
        break
      case String:
        console.log("region")
        break
    }
    this.selectedGeoArea = event
  }
```

now, `selectedGeoArea` is then passed as input to another component

```
<text-search  [selectedGeoArea]="selectedGeoArea"></text-search>


export class TextSearchComponent {
  @Input() selectedGeoArea: any

  buildQuery(): string {
    switch (this.selectedGeoArea) {
      case City:
        return `${this.addressQuery}, ${this.selectedGeoArea.name}, ${this.selectedGeoArea.province.code}, ${this.selectedGeoArea.province.region}`
      case Province:
        return `${this.addressQuery}, ${this.selectedGeoArea.code}, ${this.selectedGeoArea.region}`
      case String:
        return `${this.addressQuery}, ${this.selectedGeoArea}`
    }
    return this.addressQuery
  }
```

the problem is that `buildQuery()` always returns the value of `addressQuery`, meaning that the switch is not working at all. `selectedGeoArea` has the correct value and type as set in `receiveStoreEvent()`.

what am I missing here?

Comment: `switch (this.selectedGeoArea)` -> `switch (this.selectedGeoArea.constructor)` same way you do it in the first block of code

Comment: oh that is embarassing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You either need to do the following

```js
this.selectedGeoArea = event.constructor
```

or the following

```js
switch (this.selectedGeoArea.constructor) {
  .
  .
  .
}
```

In the initial function you were matching for `event.constructor` but in the new function you were matching only for `event`.